# Big and large: why is it not correct to say 'big cappuccino'?

Tags: adjectives, usage

*Big* and *large* have similar meanings but in some cases, they are not interchangeable. Is it right that one of such contexts is when speaking about drinks and containers for liquids? For example, a latte or a mug can be large but not big. Why?

Comment: Cups - Mugs

IKEA https://www.ikea.com › ... › Coffee & tea - cups - mugs - No matter what hot beverage you fancy, whether it's a small espresso, **a big latte** or just a nice cup of tea, we'll have the perfect one for you.

Comment: Big Bottles of Champagne, Prosecco & Vodka | Big Bottles

bigbottles.co.uk  https://www.bigbottles.co.uk In most cases many of the bottles are available with free delivery. Celebrate your next occasion with **a big bottle**, perfect for you or a loved one!

Comment: T Bone Steak

Strachan Craft Butchers  https://www.strachancraftbutchers.co.uk › shop › t-bo...
The T-Bone Steak offers you the Fillet Steak on one side of the 'T', and Sirloin Steak on the other. This is **a BIG steak for BIG appetites**.

Comment: https://www.greige.co.uk › products › Nordic Sea Large Cup and Saucer - These gorgeous squat cup and saucer sets are perfect for **a big cappuccino** or large cup of tea. Each piece is totally unique in tones of blue-grey-green.

Comment: In other words, there is nothing grammatically incorrect in saying **a big cup of coffee**; it's just that the standard expression used for portion sizes in cafe price lists happens to be **large**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formally, 'large' only ever refers to physical size, whereas 'big' can refer to both physical and non-physical things (eg "big ideas"). So, there may perhaps be a belief that 'big' can be subjective.

In answer to your question though, there is no particular 'rule' about which to use for food and drink. You can have a *large* drink with your *Big* Mac, for example.

There is perhaps a desire for standardisation in retail - if one food chain does a 'large' size then perhaps the others feel they should offer the same? There is a trend for coffee chains in the UK to market drink sizes with Italian words - for example, Starbucks has used 'grande' and 'venti'; some complain that this is unclear. One burger chain, *Wendys*, used to call their upsized fries 'Biggie' and 'Great Biggie' until they changed to 'large' and 'extra large' sometime around 2006 (in my territory at least).

Comment: I would argue that "Big Mac" isn't a very convincing example of usage of the word 'big' (versus 'large'), though.

Comment: I had a big hamburger, not one of those rinky-dink sliders.

Comment: Thanks! Trends influencing word choice obviously exist. However, what about your intuition about saying 'a big cappuccino'? Does it sound okay or you can't help but suggest changing the adjective to _large_?

Comment: @Aer as I said, both are fine... 'big' sounds more subjective and less formal - but that might be how you want to say. Saying "I had a big cappuccino earlier" might be a better way of expressing that it was larger than you expected or larger than you might normally drink. Saying "I had a large cappuccino" is just a repeat of your order.

Answer (score 0):

Langeek explains the differences and similarities between [*big* and *large*](https://langeek.co/en/grammar/course/1100/big-vs-large).

> Both of these words can be used to refer to an **object's size**.  However, 'large' is more formal, and 'big' is more common in everyday conversations.

> When we want to talk about the **size of clothing**, we use 'large', not 'big'.

> When we want to refer to an **important issue or problem** we must use 'big', not 'large'.

> When we want to talk about the **amount of something**, we must use 'large', not 'big'.

This applies to the OP's example.  We say [*large latte*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=big+latte%2Clarge+latte&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

As for mug size, [both *big* and *large* are used](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=big+mug%2Clarge+mug&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3).

Comment: All true, but the OP is asking "why?" and as a native UK English speaker I have no idea whatsoever!

Comment: " However, whenever we are referring to some other things like the importance of issues, clothes, etc." (Langeek) - this is [demonstrably](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/example/english/big-problem) wrong.

Comment: I think formality is the answer for coffees. "Large" sounds classier.

Answer (score -2):

Essentially, big is for things you can measure. For example, I have a big shirt.

This gift is quite a big one.

However, large is for non-measurable items, just like much is instead of many.

For Example:

I am having a large amount of milk.

You are eating a large portion of food.

However,
Sometimes they are interchanged like:

That is a large essay (you can count how many words are in an essay)

Overall, English is a complicated language and is all the languages combined.

You need to speak English with other people to slowly understand the ins and outs of the language.

Comment: If somebody told me they were writing a big essay, I would think they meant it was important (worth a lot of marks), rather than anything to do with its length.